# Paper Clip in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice

Is there a paper clip in LibreOffice like there is in MS Office? If not, how do I get it?

Comment: Do you mean the 'help' animation, if so No there is not one and I'm quite sure you can't get one.

Comment: That paper clip animation thing is ancient :p It was removed from the default Office 2003 installation and the feature got completely removed in Office 2007. It's available in LibreOffice, but only gets triggered at certain actions, and has been replaced by a light bulb since a few years ago.

Comment: @RobinJ: sound like a nice answer - i would upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

Clippy's ancient, he must've retired by now :p
It was removed from the default Office 2003 installation and the feature got completely removed in Office 2007. It's available in LibreOffice, but only gets triggered at certain actions, and has been replaced by a light bulb since a few years ago.

To get help in LibreOffice, you just go to the *Help* menu, and choose *LibreOffice Help*.

> ### The Help Agent
>
> The Help Agent starts automatically when you are performing a task that might require some assistance.
>   The Help Agent appears in a small window in a corner of the document. To view the help for the task, click inside the Help Agent window.